# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" with Python3.9

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.9

When I use the following code from Python terminal, it's working fine as expected.

```
Jigneshs-MBP:Desktop jpolara$ python3.9
Python 3.9.1 (default, Feb  3 2021, 07:38:02)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
>>> print(response.json())
{'message': 'success', 'iss_position': {'longitude': '-54.8828', 'latitude': '-43.3500'}, 'timestamp': 1613263412}
>>>
```

But if I add same code into Python script and execute it, I get error like:

```
Jigneshs-MBP:Desktop jpolara$ python3.9 python/get_method.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jpolara/Desktop/python/get_method.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import ssl_match_hostname
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ssl import CertificateError, match_hostname
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 255, in <module>
    from socket import socket, SOCK_STREAM, create_connection
  File "/Users/jpolara/Desktop/python/socket.py", line 5, in <module>
    s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This is my script **get_method.py**:

```
Jigneshs-MBP:Desktop jpolara$ cat python/get_method.py

import requests
response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
print(response.json())
```

This is how I installed requests module.

```
python3.9 -m pip install requests
```

I'm a beginner in Python and don't know much about it. I already tried multiple solutions from the Internet to resolve the issue, but nothing was helpful. Have you seen a similar issue with Python3.9 or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't name your file `socket.py`, Python is importing that instead of the stdlib socket module.